# How to avoid "optimized out" when debug linux kernel

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, kernel, remote-debugging

I'm debugging Linux kernel on Mac (VMWare Fusion), using two Linux Virtual Machines.

I've installed `kernel-debuginfo-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64` and the debugStub works.

[image]

Then I added a breakpoint on `fchown` syscall, it breaks,

```
Breakpoint 10, SYSC_fchown (group=0, user=0, fd=<optimized out>) at fs/open.c:650
```

But I can't read `fd.file`, the value is optimized out,

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You should build with lower optimizations and `-g3`. For optimizations, use `-O1` or `-O0`. Use `-g3` because it provides maximum debug information, including symbolic constants and defines.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this? I'm presently debugging code running on a virtual machine and running into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I can't read fd.file, the value is optimized out

This happens quite often when debugging optimized code.

Your best bet is probably to `disassemble` the routine. For a small routine like this one, usually it's not difficult to tell which register the value is in, and then you can cast to the right type. E.g. if the value is in `$r9`:

```
(gdb) p *(struct file *)$r9
```